# toString(): numbers in JSON

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have QJsonObject, here is it:

```
QJsonObject({"key":"1475bee449df002422340510c355a7f8b48ea647","pts":960894,"server":"imv4.vk.com/im1976","ts":1626706149})
```

`object["key"].toString()`  - ok, it returns `1475bee449df002422340510c355a7f8b48ea647`
`object["server"].toString()` - ok, it returns `imv4.vk.com/im1976`
`object["ts"].toString()` - fail, returns `""`.
`object["pts"].toString()` - fail, returns `""`.

Yes, i can do `QString::number(object["ts"].toInt());`, but it isn't solution: value can be greater then `MAXINT`. Type of `object["ts"]` is `double`:

```
QJsonValue(double, 1626706149)
```

But `object["ts"].toDouble()` returns `1.62671e+09`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide an exact code not *"I have QJsonObject, it seems like this"*. Because it should not look like that.

Comment: Still the code cannot look like that top line. It is understood you are showing the contents of that object, though. Please try to do qDebug() << object["pts"]; and let us know.

Comment: I wrote that it is double, but ok, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is explained there is a double value in QJsonValue object. A quick try confirms it won't convert to string for some reason, though it converts to 64 bit int with the casting.

```
QJsonValue jv((double)9999960902);
qDebug() << jv.toString();
qDebug() << jv.toInt();
qDebug() << (qint64)jv.toDouble();
```

And the output is:

```
""
0
9999960902
```

Comment: I actually tested that in my 32-bit project. Yes. Having 64 bit integer you will be able to convert that to string as well if needed. It is printed, huh.